# Hadoop Hive external table location?

Tags: hadoop, external

I am Working on HIVE. Where should i create a external table. Inside my local file system  OR Inside HDFS file system ?. which is recommended for projects.

Comment: It's always going to be within HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be within a filesystem accessible by the cluster nodes. While 99% of the times this will mean the cluster file system and 99% of the time this will mean HDFS, this is not strictly true: Hadoop can access other filesystems, trivial examples being [`S3FileSystem`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/S3FileSystem.html) or [Azure blobs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-blob-storage/).

One place you *cannot* use for external Hive tables is your local filesystem. A local file URI will be meaningless for a remote node. It may work for a pseudo-distributed (single node) 'cluster', but not in real world.